# Magento 2 REST API search in Product Media

Tags: magento2, product, rest-api, media-images

I try to find all media IDs of one product with the position number 1 in

```
HOST/rest/all/V1/products/SKU/media
```

Everthing I can read tells me to use this:

```
GET
HOST/rest/V1/products/SKU/media?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=position&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=1
```

But whatever I do the result is the full list of the SKU which has 5 Pictures.

Comment: Can you list an example to make the question clear?

Comment: The second code is my example. I am looking for the FIeld = ID and the Value = 1. I am using Postman and GET Method withthe URL from abouve.

Comment: you cannot use [searchCriteria] in this endpoint, if you looked at this interface [Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementInterface], Then go to the [getList], you only can see that this function has one parameter  and it is the SKU, there is nothing related to the [searchCriteria], You may need to call this endpoint instead  [/V1/products/:sku/media/:entryId], like this [HOST/rest/V1/products/SKU/media/1].

Comment: How great! So does that mean that you can step into arrays with /name/ ? I just tried but could not getinto "types": []. Alo where do I find these informations?

Comment: Just realised my example was actually wrong. I actually need to get all values of Postion 1 (for example). So is tehre a ways to seaarch for SKU and then position? (I did edit that in the Text abouve)